# How to split string into 2 parts after certain position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example I have some random string:

```
str = "26723462345"
```

And I want to split it in 2 parts after 6-th char. How to do this correctly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This should do it

```
[str[0..5], str[6..-1]]
```

or

```
 [str.slice(0..5), str.slice(6..-1)]
```

Really should check out http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html

Comment: or str[0...6] and you write everywhere the key value "6"

Answer (score 13):

Here’s on option. Be aware, however, that it will mutate your original string:

```
part1, part2 = str.slice!(0...6), str

p part1  # => "267234"
p part2  # => "62345"
p str    # => "62345"
```

### Update

In the years since I wrote this answer I’ve come to agree with the commenters complaining that it might be excessively clever. Below are a few other options that don’t mutate the original string.

Caveat: This one will only work with ASCII characters.

```
str.unpack("a6a*")
# => ["267234", "62345"]
```

The next one uses the magic variable `$'`, which returns the part of the string after the most recent Regexp match:

```
part1, part2 = str[/.{6}/], $'
p [part1, part2]
# => ["267234", "62345"]
```

And this last one uses a lookbehind to split the string in the right place without returning any extra parts:

```
p str.split(/(?<=^.{6})/)
# => ["267234", "62345"]
```

Comment: I like this better than mine. Although I'd add str = part1 + part2 at end so string doesn't change.

Comment: Well if you want to keep `str` unchanged then your solution is better I think.

Comment: What about: str, part1, part2 = str.clone, str.slice!(0..6), str

Comment: I won't go as far to say that functional style is *always* better than imperative style, but IMHO this inplace change is just too clever to be advisable.

Answer (score 4):

The best way IMO is `string.scan(/.{6}/)`

```
irb(main)> str
=> "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
irb(main)> str.scan(/.{13}/)
=> ["abcdefghijklm", "nopqrstuvwxyz"]
```

Comment: `str.scan(/.{6}/)` on OP's example returns only the first part.

Answer (score 4):

```
_, part1, part2 = str.partition /.{6}/
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-partition

Comment: Nice. Bonus: you can split so that the last part is always 6 chars like this: `part1, part2, _ = str.partition /.{6}$/`

Answer (score 1):

As a fun answer, how about:

```
str.split(/(^.{1,6})/)[1..-1]
```

This works because split returns the capture group matches, in addition to the parts of the string before and after the regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reusable version for you:

```
str       = "26723462345"
n         = str.length
boundary  = 6
head      = str.slice(0, boundary) # => "267234" 
tail      = str.slice(boundary, n) # => "62345"
```

It also preserves the original string, which may come in handy later in the program.

Comment: You can use `-1` instead of having to get the string's length.